# Jobs beta - CV completion criteria

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Does the current 400 character experience text "minimum" on the jobs beta seem a little excessive to others, or is it just me?

As a suggestion, I've have thought that 250 characters might be a more realistic minimum, especially when the list of technology used already covers a fair degree of the sort of information you may wish to convey. (Specifically, I'm thinking about situations where you're adding experience relating a role that occurred several years past, where the details may not be particularly fresh in your mind, or situations where (due to privacy/NDAs) you can only divulge a limited amount of information.

On a similar basis:

- The number of projects needed (currently 5) also seems a bit excessive (especially as some employers don't like staff members directly associating themselves with a given project).
- Having to add achievements text against education may not always be possible. For example, having finished my degree in 1995 I've little memory of
  the sort of projects I undertook at the time. (Beyond occasional flashbacks to Ada coding in the dark of night.) :-)

Just a thought - hence the discussion tag.

Comment: I agree with this.  The percentage should be eliminated as it gives a false impression to the user that he or she is never done.  For instance, I am at 95% completion with absolutely nothing to add yet that 5% bothers me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing average English, 400 characters ends up being about 80 words.  For comparison, the question you just asked has 1132 characters and 186 words. The longest paragraph has 497 characters/81 words. Less than a paragraph to describe your responsibilities at a job you held for months seems reasonable.

My problem with these counts is that they're giving you feedback at the wrong level of abstraction. A specific character count is magic-numbery and a weird target metric for a section of your CV, that's why it seems weird.